# xcodeのシミュレーターの向きの設定について　Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

Tags: xcode

最近xcodeをアップグレードしました。バージョンはVersion 7.0.1 (7A1001)です。
新たに縦持ちの画面でアプリを作成しているのですが
シミュレーターの向きがデフォで横持ちになっています。

いつも通りに向きを変更しようとしたのですが
前のように設定する項目がなく
設定をどこからすればいいのかわかりません。

xcodeのヘルプに問い合わせをしようとしたのですが、
その件に対して問い合わせるページがわかりませんでした。

まず向きが変えられなければ始まらないのです。
どなたか回答お願いします。

追記
[image: シミュレーターの向きを変える設定が行方不明です。]

このようになっていて、どこから設定をすればいいのかわかりません。

タイトル画像を縦持ち用にしているので、まず画面と画像のサイズ違いでうまい具合にシミュレーターが動いてくれずフリーズしてしまいます。
ですから、シミュレーター立ち上げ後に向きを変えても結局起動ができずに終わってしまいます。

現状のエラーはこちらです。
fullPathForFilename: No file found at title.png.

Harawo様のその設定項目は、前のバージョンでは普通に見ることができて設定もうまくできていたのですが、今のバージョンで同じことをしようとするとまずその項目が見当たりません。

その設定ができるところを探しているのですが、ないのです…。

[image: ターゲット]

初歩的なところから理解できていなくて本当に申し訳ありません、TARGETSとはどこからいけるのでしょうか？一つ前のスクショは、左側のウインドウの青いZibakureiをクリックした結果です。確か前のバージョンの時はここから設定ができたと思うのです。

Comment: スクショですが、`PROJECT`の設定な気がします。`TARGETS`の`*.app`の設定にHarawoさんの項目有りませんか？私の方は同じバージョンで同項目が表示されています。

Answer (score 1):

Xcodeのその画面からですと、クリック２〜３回でデバイスの回転設定を開けます。

まず、下の赤丸部のボタンをクリックして、プロジェクトリストとターゲットリストを表示させます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

リストが表示されると、プロジェクトリストでアプリが選択状態になっているかと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そこで、ターゲットリストのほうのアプリをクリックして選択します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あとは、（２）部分で General が選択されていれば、（３）あたりに Device Orientation設定があるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

考えられる原因のひとつです。この線はあまり濃くないのですが、念のためというレベルで回答しておきます。
プロジェクトの**General**項目で、**Device Orientation**の**Portrait**のチェックが外れていると、シミュレータのデバイスの向きが、起動時横向きになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

下記で出来ませんか？
`Hardware` > `Rotate Left`or`Rotate Right`

・ショートカットキー
`Command＋→`or`Command＋←`